# Use overridePendingTransition after startActivity i can't see the activity but it can accept click event

Tags: android

I write code such as：

```
    startActivity(intent);
    this.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.menu_enter, R.anim.menu_exit);
```

but i can not see the target activity,it looks like to be translucent,when i lock the screen and reopen,it appears! Have you come across the problem and help me ,thanks!

anim xml：

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`enter code here`
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_quad"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="0"/>
<alpha
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_quad"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"/>
</set>
```

PS：Even if i use android.R.anim.fade_in or out, problem also occurs

Comment: check your animation and provide your code

Comment: post your menu_enter.xml

Comment: i have post my  menu_enter.xml.